# Unable to use CSS to remove a button on a toolbar in Sharepoint Web

Tags: css, sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-2016, content-editor

I have a weppart page I'm editing in SharePoint Web. I have an excel workbook display webpart in a column. The webpart has a summary toolbar for open in excel, download, and such. The toolbar has multiple buttons displayed to the user that I want to remove. Foe example, the first one is Edit in Excel.

I added a content editor for CSS and used 

.cui-ctl-mdedium,
.cui-ctl-mdediumlabel
Display:None;

I've tried multiple classes, targeting just the webpart, using !important and such with no luck. Any thoughts?

[Element/Class info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdUTz.png)

Comment: `.cui-ctl-mdediumlabel` -- you've got a typo there. Also, I don't see the first tag that you referenced in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've written that selector correctly? The class name is actually `.cui-ctl-mediumlabel` ... you've written it with a "1". Not much to do in this case without code or anything to actually try it out. Have you tried solving your problem with your browser's dev tools adding rules?

Comment: Yeah I checked my CSS file, just had the typo here (Updated). 

My sharepoint site is pretty locked down for me... I was told by our sharepoint team that I'd have to use CSS.

Comment: Again: have you tried using your browser's dev tools (Ctrl + Shift + i) and to add CSS rules to that specific element? Maybe also visibility: hidden?

Comment: Right. Visibility: Hidden; and Display: None; work there.